# Problem authorizing client with django-oAuth-toolkit Authorization Code flow

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-oauth-toolkit

I have been following the django-oAuth-toolkit [documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). In the Authorization Code step, I have registered an application as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot given in the documentation]

But then the next step is given like this:

> To start the Authorization code flow go to this URL which is the same as shown below:
> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=vW1RcAl7Mb0d5gyHNQIAcH110lWoOW2BmWJIero8&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/noexist/callback`

But when I replace my client id and ping that URL it redirects me to the following URL:
`http://localhost:8000/noexist/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=Code+challenge+required.`

I have tried to google that error but it's such a common keyword that I am unable to find anything that is related to my issue. I am probably missing something obvious, I am new to Python and Django.

Note: In the documentation screenshot there is one form field missing which is there in my local environment. It's the algorithm field.
[image: Screenshot of my local application]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After debugging for so many hours I came to this, please include it in your settings.py file and it works. Maybe it is a bug since we defined our app as confidential with authorization_code grant type but oauth_provider is thinking it as public and trying to validate for pkce.

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    "PKCE_REQUIRED": False
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Was it not there in the documentation? Did I miss something?

Comment: It is mentioned in the changelog for version Release 2.0.0 breaking changes:
https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#warning